# JAVA: Calling a class from another class

Tags: java

In my src/ folder I have the main.java file, and within the project folder, I have the other file BeerSong.java. BeerSong.java is a wile loop of the song "99 bottles of beer on the wall". How would I call BeerSong.java into main.java.

**Requirements**: Main method that calls another method "Ninety_Nine_Bottles_Of_Beer_On_The_Wall that is in the file called BeerSong.java.

Project Structure
Project

....> .idea

....> out

....> src

```
  ...>Main.java (class)
```

....> .gitignore

....> BeerSong.java

---

**BeerSong.java Code**

```
 public class Ninety_Nine_Bottles_Of_Beer_On_The_Wall {

     public static void main(String[] args) {


    int bottlesOfBeer = 99; //Initial Number of Bottles to begin with
    String word = "bottles";

    while (bottlesOfBeer> 0)
     {
       if (bottlesOfBeer == 1) {
          word = "bottle";
        }
       else {
          word = "bottles";
        }
        System.out.println(bottlesOfBeer + " " + word + " of beer on the wall, " + bottlesOfBeer + " " + word + " of beer");
        System.out.println("Take one down, pass it around, ");
        bottlesOfBeer = bottlesOfBeer - 1;

           if (bottlesOfBeer > 0) {
          System.out.println(bottlesOfBeer + " " + word + " of beer on the wall.\n");
       } else {
          System.out.println("No more bottles of beer on the wall\n");
       }
        } //End of While Song loop
    } // End of Main
```

} // End of Ninety_Nine_Bottles_of_Beer

Comment: You should *probably* move the logic for the song *out* of the `main` method of the `Ninety_Nine_Bottles_Of_Beer_On_The_Wall` class, and create a function instead.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Ninety_Nine_Bottles_Of_Beer_On_The_Wall`'s `main` method is static, and the public class should be automatically visible to the rest of your project, you should be able to call the method from `Main.java` with:

```
Ninety_Nine_Bottles_Of_Beer_On_The_Wall.main({});
```

However, in this case it's probably best to make a function rather than a completely separate class. Because there are no attributes and only one method, it seems redundant to make `Ninety_Nine_Bottles_Of_Beer_On_The_Wall` it's own class.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name from `BeerSong.java` to `Ninety_Nine_Bottles_Of_Beer_On_The_Wall.java` and move that file into src folder.

Now you have two options

1. Execute `Ninety_Nine_Bottles_Of_Beer_On_The_Wall.java`
2. In `Main.java` call `Ninety_Nine_Bottles_Of_Beer_On_The_Wall.main(new String[0])`